# Git Folder Difference between between two times for a single branch in TFS

Tags: github, azure-devops

I am newbie to git and TFS and I wanted to get difference between the files that have changed from time t1 to t2 committed for a single branch. I have tried using git diff master master@{yyyy-mm-dd} format but this does not seem to be working for me. Is there any other method by which I can get this difference.
I wanted to compare what has been changed on the repository between two time frames.

Comment: Using git log to get the specific time of commit, then using the git diff ...(Bittu said) to get the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should provide you what you want:

```
git diff --stat @{2017-04-19}..@{2017-04-24} -p
```

You can use [this](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged/1.7.9) as well to get diff between commits

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This command seems to be working fine for my local branch.. I wanted to know if it is possible to get the same command with additional parameters for a branch hosted in TFS(i.e a global repository in TFS)

Comment: @developer_ak No, but you can clone the remote branch to local, then call git diff command. On the other hand, there is the REST API to compare, but don't meet your requirement. https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/diffs